# Angular function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to execute a function inside ng-repeat to convert date. How can i parse a angular result in a function?

Field name in database is dataf

I tried diferent ways but no one works...

```
<tr ng-repeat="detail in details| filter:search_query">

<td><b>{{detail.nom}}</b></td>
<td>{{detail.descripcio}}</td>
<td>{{datareves(detail.datafet) }} </td>
<td>{{detail.visible}}</td>
```

and

```
getInfo();
function getInfo(){
$http.post('empDetails.php').success(function(data){
$scope.details = data;
});
 }

$scope.datareves = function(details.datafet) {
    var res = dataf.split(" ");
    var res2 = res[0].split("-");
    var final = res2[2] + "-" + res2[1] + "-" + res2[0];
    return (final);
 };
```

Comment: Change to this function(dataf)

Answer (score 0):

Your function should look like this

```
$scope.datareves = function(dataf) {
var res = dataf.split(" ");
var res2 = res[0].split("-");
var final = res2[2] + "-" + res2[1] + "-" + res2[0];
return (final);
};
```

notice the change to the first line. The name of the variable you used in the function was not the same as the name being passed into the function.

You can read more about javascript function definitions here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_definition.asp

Comment: Please provide some mock data, a plunkr would also help.